# vue 3 axios cannot add params gives TS2345: Argument of type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vue.js, axios, vuejs3

I am trying to make an axios call but getting an error shown below.  Using vue 3/ vite/ typescript for my project.  In my IDE params is underlined and highlighted red.  The code does work but wont build.

My Axios call

```
import axios  from "axios";
```

> ```
> async userstatusconfirmed() {
>   let url = "/auth/amiconfirmed";
>   let headers = authHeader();
>   let params = {withCredentials: true}
>   await axios.get(url, {params, headers}
>   ).then((response) => {
>     if (response.status == 200) {
>       if (response.data.confirmed == true) {
>         this.$router.push({ name: "home" });
>       }
>     }
>   });
> },
> ```

```
TS2345: Argument of type '{ params: { withCredentials: boolean; }; headers: Record<string, string>; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AxiosRequestConfig<any>'.   Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'params' does not exist in type 'AxiosRequestConfig<any>'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The types error you're getting is weird (I can't repro it, using axios `0.27.2`).

You might want to create a *runnable* mcve on codesandbox.io or similar.

---

However, `withCredentials` is an AxiosRequestConfig member, it doesn't go inside `params`:

```js
userstatusconfirmed() {
  const url = "/auth/amiconfirmed";
  const config = { 
    headers: authHeader(), 
    withCredentials: true
  };

  return axios.get(url, config)
    .then(/* ... */);
}
```

Comment: The issue was I was using a very packages and setting up a docker enviroment with latest versions fixed it.